# Criterion for real roots of 4th order polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, roots

Suppose we are given a polynomial equation of the form 
$$ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2+dx +e = 0 $$ with $a,b,c,d,e\in\mathbb{R}$.

Does there exist conditions on the coefficients $a,b,c,d,e$ such that the equation produces only real roots?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Nature_of_the_roots. Also, did you write it correctly?

Comment: The Ruth-Hurwitz criterion may be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_stability_criterion

Comment: @MostafaAyaz how?